# Custom RPM to deliver files and backup any pre-existing files of same name

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am planning to create an RPM which will deliver some customized files (which are totally new) and will also replace some pre-existing files like /etc/resolv.conf file. While I am able to deliver a new /etc/resolv.conf file using my customized RPM, I want to backup previously existing file and that should come back in action if I uninstall this customized RPM. Any ideas of how this can be achieved will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you where talking about configuration file that you deliver with your package, then I would say that the `%config` statement in your `%file` section is the way to go.  See: [RPM, %config, and (noreplace)](http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/~jw35/docs/rpm_config.html)

However, in your case you are talking about changing file that is provided by an other package.

This, while not optimal, is possible, but then you will need to backup and restore the file with the `%pre` and `%postun` scriptlets.

Your scriptlet can rely on the `$1` variable that will tell your package if the current operation is install/uninstall or an upgrade.

See the **Install/Erase-time Scripts** section in the
[Maximum RPM book, Chapter 13. Inside the Spec File](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html)

---

**Example:**

Suppose there is an `existing-1.0-norach.rpm` installed on your system with:

```
%files
%config(norplace) /etc/existing
```

And you wish to have your `custom-0.1-noarch.rpm` that need to replace `/etc/existing`:

You could have in your `custom.spec` file:

```
%files
%config(noreplace) /etc/%{name}/existing
```

and:

```
%post
# backup existing file, and replace with a symlink to custom file.
if [ $1 -eq 1 ] ; then
    mv /etc/existing /etc/existing.%{name}
    ln -s /etc/%{name}/existing /etc/existing
fi

%preun
# remove symlink to custom file and restore original.
if [ ( $1 -eq 0 ) -a ( -l /etc/existing ) ] ; then
    rm /etc/existing
    mv /etc/existing.%{name} /etc/existing
fi
```

---

**Notes:**

- It is a bad Idea to have more than one package that provides the same file. For this reason the example above provide a different file.
- The symlink is not part of the package payload, but it points to a file that belongs to the package. This way the user can figure out what file belongs to what package, with `rpm -ql`, `rpm -qf` and by looking at what the symlink points at.
- If files will be modified by the user the `%config(noreplace)` will usually do the right thing. The same is true if `existing-1.0-norach.rpm` will be installed after `custom-0.1-noarch.rpm` or will be removed before it.
- Consider making `custom-0.1-noarch.rpm` `%require` `existing-1.0-norach.rpm`. This make your setup less flexible, but you will not need to consider all the permutation of installation order.
- In some distribution some configuration files are not provided by packages, but instead generated from other files. IIRC, this is true for `resolve.conf` in RedHat and Suse based distribution, and the source of truth for this file resides somewhere under `/etc/sysconfig/`. So you should not try this recipe for such files.

---

**Warning:** I have seen this technique misused. Specs that are written this way usually becomes a horrible mess, that behaves unexpectedly, interact poorly with other packages, and steal your soul to long and ugly debugging session. If it is possible at all, try to use `%config` and `%config(noreplace)`, that is already baked into RPM, and while don't do exactly what you ask for, do its thing in simple and reliable way.

---

Comment: `%pre` needs to be used - `%post` will have your version of the file already (I have an edit queued). Also, you are beginning to get into areas that may be beyond RPM and something like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/puppet/what-is-puppet) may be more what you need.